# Declaring and Defining Variables and Functions in Separate Files

Tags: c++, variables, declaration, definition, extern

I'm confused about how to define and declare my variables and functions across multiple files WITHOUT resorting to global variables.
Let's say I wanted to have separate header and source files declaring and defining variables and functions outside of 'main.cpp', to be used in 'main.cpp'.

EDIT: Apologies for my unclear example, but there will only ever be one balloon. I don't want balloon to be an object. It's just to hold some variables and functions.

```
//balloon.h
bool inflated = true;
void pop();
```

-

```
//balloon.cpp
#include "balloon.h"
void pop()
{
    inflated = false;
}
```

-

```
//main.cpp
#include "balloon.h"
int main()
{
    pop();
    return 0;
}
```

If I do this it gives me errors for having multiple definitions of 'inflated', and that it was first declared in 'balloon.cpp'.

If I use 'extern', it works, but gives me warnings about initializing and declaring 'inflated' in 'balloon.h'.

If I decide not to define inflated in balloon.h, it gives me errors about an undefined reference to 'inflated'.

What is the standard way of going about this? Am I missing some key information of variable/function declaration/definition across multiple files?

Comment: What you're describing **is** a global variable.

Comment: But I don't want to use a global variable.

Comment: If you want to use a variable "across multiple files", then what you're asking for is a global variable.  The alternatives are to pass the variable in as a function argument, or to encapsulate them together in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight away it should be

```
//balloon.h
extern bool inflated;
void pop();
```

---

```
//balloon.cpp
#include "balloon.h"

bool inflated = true;

void pop() {
    inflated = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard" way, but apparently what you're aiming for is like a single logical object with operations: some functions that operate on some common shared variables.

That was the original module concept of e.g. C and Modula-2.

In C one declared the variables as `static` in the implementation file, in order to not have their names exposed to the linker. This is called internal linkage. In C++ this use of `static` is deprecated, and instead one should preferentially use an anonymous namespace:

*balloon.h*

```
#pragma once
auto is_inflated() -> bool;
void inflate();
```

*balloon.cpp*

```
#include "ballon.h"

namespace {
    bool inflated = true;
}  // namespace anon

auto is_inflated() -> bool { return ::inflated; }
void inflate() { ::inflated = true; }
```

But instead of this old-fashioned module-as-a-logical-variable, consider defining a class.

That's what classes are *for*.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use global variables, then create class to do the OOP style.

```
class A 
{
public:
bool inflated = true;
void pop();
}
```

You can separate specification and implementation like you did in question, it would look like this:

```
void A::pop()
{
   bool inflated = false;
}
```

And then include .h file in main and create an object of a class: `A* a = new A();` 
For more reference go here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/